# Display only future events (cpt)

Tags: php, wordpress, date

My current code shows 5 posts from the cpt 'events'. This is the code i'm using:

```
//get post type ==> events
global $post;
$args = array(
      'post_type' => 'events',
      'numberposts' => $data['home_events_count'],
      'orderby' => 'meta_value',
      'meta_key' => 'timestamp_earth_event_start_date',
      'meta_query' => $meta_query
);
```

I want to filter out posts (events) that their 'timestamp_earth_event_start_date' are older than the current date.

I've tried to modify the code myself, but still past events are shown.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: I'd update this question with what timestamp_earth_event_start_date is referring to? What type of field is this, a custom field?

Comment: timestamp_earth_event_start_date is the custom field that holds the start date of the event

Comment: timestamp_earth?  are you keeping your functionality open so that you can support your code on other planets?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one passing query string

```
$numposts=$data['home_events_count'];
    query_posts('post_type=events
    &post_status=publish&numberposts=$numposts
    &posts_per_page=1
    &meta_key=timestamp_earth_event_start_date
    &orderby=meta_value_num
    &order=DESC')
```

By passing array

```
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' =  'events' ,
    'meta_key' => 'timestamp_earth_event_start_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
);
$event_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Other option you can add filter for the query like

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'my_posts_orderby_date', 10, 2 );
function my_posts_orderby_date( $orderby, $query ) {
    global $wpdb;
    return " CAST( $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value AS DATE ) " . $query->get( 'order' );
}
```

Comment: thank you so much dianuj! I've tried all 3, and it seems that the second one is working but with a minor bug. It hides the past events and shows the future events, but it also adds some extra lines of 'events' without title, description or anything. This is the link to the full code: http://pastebin.com/W50fnhWk

Comment: Sory this was not clear *"but it also adds some extra lines of 'events' without title, description or anything"* and for the past events not showing because there is a limit of  posts if you want all events posts then you have to pass the `nopaging` parameter to `true` then all the post of events you can get otherwise it takes the default limit for the posts

Comment: The query should only display 1 event, since there is only 1 event that is not older than the current date, but instead this is what i get:

<div class="event_entry"><div class="title">My Event</div></div>
<div class="event_entry"><div class="title"></div></div>
<div class="event_entry"><div class="title"></div></div>
<div class="event_entry"><div class="title"></div></div>

In other words, the code does filters out old events, but it still adds empty entries for other events as well. Maybe there is a problem with my foreach($event_posts as $post) ?

Comment: Things in question i have already answered i can't guess the loop or other problems in the code :)